# Как удалить первичный ключ с одновременным удалением ссылок, т.е. внешних ключей, ссылающихся на данный PK?

Tags: sql, oracle

Нужно из таблицы удалить первичный ключ с одновременным удалением ссылающихся на данный ПК внешних ключей.

Какой командой это можно реализовать?

Например:

```
ALTER TABLE SOTR_1 ADD CONSTRAINT FK_T1_T2_Cascade2 FOREIGN KEY (codePos)
REFERENCES DOLGN_1(code) ON DELETE CASCADE
;
```

Теперь нужно удалить ПК. Можно ли воспользоваться вот этой командой:

```
ALTER TABLE SOTR_1 DROP PRIMARY KEY code
```

Comment: ссылки это связные записи в других таблицах? настройте каскадное удаление в свойствах связей (внешних ключей тех таблиц)

Comment: Поясните, что в вашем понимании есть "удаление первичного ключа" и что - "удаление ссылок". Если еще будут DDL-скрипты таблиц - будет просто замечательно.

Comment: Удаление производится командой `DELETE`, а что подразумевается под "одновременным"? В одной транзакции, одной командой, иначе? Я **предполагаю**, что речь идет о FOREIGN KEY c ON DELETE CASCADE - но это именно **предположение**.

Comment: Посмотрите https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#i1036780 , ищите ON DELETE clause. Если у вас останутся вопросы - добавьте в вопрос скрипты определения таблиц, как предложил @Dmitriy.

Comment: ALTER TABLE SOTR_1
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_T1_T2_Cascade2
   FOREIGN KEY (codePos) REFERENCES DOLGN_1(code) ON DELETE CASCADE;
 Теперь нужно удалить ПК. Для этого нужно воспользоваться вот этой командой: ALTER TABLE SOTR_1 DROP PRIMARY KEY code ?

Answer (score 3):

Удалить ПК (*primary key*) с одновременным удалением привязанных внешних ключей (*foreign keys*) можно следующим образом. Подготовим схему:

```
create table t1 (id number primary key);
create table t2 (id number constraint fk_t2 references t1 (id));
create table t3 (id number constraint fk_t3 references t1 (id));

alter table t1 drop primary key;
```

> ORA-02273: this unique/primary key is referenced by some foreign keys
>   02273. 00000 -  "this unique/primary key is referenced by some foreign keys"
>   *Cause:    Self-evident.
>   *Action:   **Remove all references to the key before the key is to be dropped.**

Слепо верим тому, о чём говорится в сообщении об ошибке и удаляем все привязанные внешние ключи, а затем сам первичный ключ:

```
<<drop_pk>> declare tableName constant varchar2 (32) := upper ('t1');   
begin
    for r in (
        select r.owner, r.table_name, r.constraint_name 
        from all_constraints r 
        join all_constraints c on r.r_constraint_name = c.constraint_name and r.constraint_type = 'R'
        where c.table_name = tableName
    ) loop 
        execute immediate 'alter table '||r.owner||'.'||r.table_name||' drop constraint '||r.constraint_name;
        dbms_output.put_line ('Table '||r.owner||'.'||r.table_name||' altered ('||r.constraint_name||' droped).');
    end loop;
    execute immediate 'alter table '||user||'.'||tableName||' drop primary key';
    dbms_output.put_line ('Table '||user||'.'||tableName||' altered (primary key droped).');
end;
/
```

> Table HR.T2 altered (FK_T2 droped).
>   Table HR.T3 altered (FK_T3 droped).
>   Table HR.T1 altered (primary key droped).

PS: можно преобразовать в хранимую процедуру, если используется часто, что в свою очередь маловероятно.